# Need some help - something breaking IE on Drupal 6 site

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-cycle

Trying to use IE debugger to figure out why certain css isn't rendering at the tops of some 'types' of Drupal pages. It looks like header and suckerfish menu css not working in IE.

Debugger stops at an error in this code in the jQuery Cycle Plugin

```
(function($){var ver="2.88";if($.support==undefined){$.support={opacity:!($.browser.msie)};}function debug(s){if($.fn.cycle.debug){log(s);}}function log(){if(window.console&&window.console.log){window.console.log("[cycle] "+Array.prototype.join.call(arguments," "));}}$.fn.cycle=function(options,arg2){var o={s:this.selector,c:this.context};if(this.length===0&&options!="stop"){if(!$.isReady&&o.s){log("DOM not ready, queuing slideshow");$(function(){$(o.s,o.c).cycle(options,arg2);});return this;}log("terminating; zero elements found by selector"+($.isReady?"":" (DOM not ready)"));return this;}return this.each(function(){var opts=handleArguments(this,options,arg2);if(opts===false){return;}opts.updateActivePagerLink=opts.updateActivePagerLink||$.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink;if(this.cycleTimeout){clearTimeout(this.cycleTimeout);}this.cycleTimeout=this.cyclePause=0;var $cont=$(this);var $slides=opts.slideExpr?$(opts.slideExpr,this):$cont.children();var els=$slides.get();if(els.length<2){log("terminating; too few slides: "+els.length);return;}var opts2=buildOptions($cont,$slides,els,opts,o);if(opts2===false){return;}var startTime=opts2.continuous?10:getTimeout(els[opts2.currSlide],els[opts2.nextSlide],opts2,!opts2.rev);if(startTime){startTime+=(opts2.delay||0);if(startTime<10){startTime=10;}debug("first timeout: "+startTime);this.cycleTimeout=setTimeout(function(){go(els,opts2,0,(!opts2.rev&&!opts.backwards));},startTime);}});};function handleArguments(cont,options,arg2){if(cont.cycleStop==undefined){cont.cycleStop=0;}if(options===undefined||options===null){options={};}if(options.constructor==String){switch(options){case"destroy":case"stop":var opts=$(cont).data("cycle.opts");if(!opts){return false;}cont.cycleStop++;if(cont.cycleTimeout){clearTimeout(cont.cycleTimeout);}cont.cycleTimeout=0;$(cont).removeData("cycle.opts");if(options=="destroy"){destroy(opts);}return false;case"toggle":cont.cyclePause=(cont.cyclePause===1)?0:1;checkInstantResume(cont.cyclePause,arg2,cont);return false;case"pause":cont.cyclePause=1;return false;case"resume":cont.cyclePause=0;checkInstantResume(false,arg2,cont);return false;case"prev":case"next":var opts=$(cont).data("cycle.opts");if(!opts){log('options not found, "prev/next" ignored');return false;}$.fn.cycle[options](opts);return false;default:options={fx:options};}return options;}else{if(options.constructor==Number){var num=options;options=$(cont).data("cycle.opts");if(!options){log("options not found, can not advance slide");return false;}if(num<0||num>=options.elements.length){log("invalid slide index: "+num);return false;}options.nextSlide=num;if(cont.cycleTimeout){clearTimeout(cont.cycleTimeout);cont.cycleTimeout=0;}if(typeof arg2=="string"){options.oneTimeFx=arg2;}go(options.elements,options,1,num>=options.currSlide);return false;}}return options;function checkInstantResume(isPaused,arg2,cont){if(!isPaused&&arg2===true){var options=$(cont).data("cycle.opts");if(!options){log("options not found, can not resume");return false;}if(cont.cycleTimeout){clearTimeout(cont.cycleTimeout);cont.cycleTimeout=0;}go(options.elements,options,1,(!opts.rev&&!opts.backwards));}}}function removeFilter(el,opts){if(!$.support.opacity&&opts.cleartype&&el.style.filter){try{el.style.removeAttribute("filter");}catch(smother){}}}function destroy(opts){if(opts.next){$(opts.next).unbind(opts.prevNextEvent);}if(opts.prev){$(opts.prev).unbind(opts.prevNextEvent);}if(opts.pager||opts.pagerAnchorBuilder){$.each(opts.pagerAnchors||[],function(){this.unbind().remove();});}opts.pagerAnchors=null;if(opts.destroy){opts.destroy(opts);}}function buildOptions($cont,$slides,els,options,o){var opts=$.extend({},$.fn.cycle.defaults,options||{},$.metadata?$cont.metadata():$.meta?$cont.data():{});if(opts.autostop){opts.countdown=opts.autostopCount||els.length;}var cont=$cont[0];$cont.data("cycle.opts",opts);opts.$cont=$cont;opts.stopCount=cont.cycleStop;opts.elements=els;opts.before=opts.before?[opts.before]:[];opts.after=opts.after?[opts.after]:[];opts.after.unshift(function(){opts.busy=0;});if(!$.support.opacity&&opts.cleartype){opts.after.push(function(){removeFilter(this,opts);});}if(opts.continuous){opts.after.push(function(){go(els,opts,0,(!opts.rev&&!opts.backwards));});}saveOriginalOpts(opts);if(!$.support.opacity&&opts.cleartype&&!opts.cleartypeNoBg){clearTypeFix($slides);}if($cont.css("position")=="static"){$cont.css("position","relative");}if(opts.width){$cont.width(opts.width);}if(opts.height&&opts.height!="auto"){$cont.height(opts.height);}if(opts.startingSlide){opts.startingSlide=parseInt(opts.startingSlide);}else{if(opts.backwards){opts.startingSlide=els.length-1;}}if(opts.random){opts.randomMap=[];for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){opts.randomMap.push(i);}opts.randomMap.sort(function(a,b){return Math.random()-0.5;});opts.randomIndex=1;opts.startingSlide=opts.randomMap[1];}else{if(opts.startingSlide>=els.length){opts.startingSlide=0;}}opts.currSlide=opts.startingSlide||0;var first=opts.startingSlide;$slides.css({position:"absolute",top:0,left:0}).hide().each(function(i){var z;if(opts.backwards){z=first?i<=first?els.length+(i-first):first-i:els.length-i;}else{z=first?i>=first?els.length-(i-first):first-i:els.length-i;}$(this).css("z-index",z);});$(els[first]).css("opacity",1).show();removeFilter(els[first],opts);if(opts.fit&&opts.width){$slides.width(opts.width);}if(opts.fit&&opts.height&&opts.height!="auto"){$slides.height(opts.height);}var reshape=opts.containerResize&&!$cont.innerHeight();if(reshape){var maxw=0,maxh=0;for(var j=0;j<els.length;j++){var $e=$(els[j]),e=$e[0],w=$e.outerWidth(),h=$e.outerHeight();if(!w){w=e.offsetWidth||e.width||$e.attr("width");}if(!h){h=e.offsetHeight||e.height||$e.attr("height");}maxw=w>maxw?w:maxw;maxh=h>maxh?h:maxh;}if(maxw>0&&maxh>0){$cont.css({width:maxw+"px",height:maxh+"px"});}}if(opts.pause){$cont.hover(function(){this.cyclePause++;},function(){this.cyclePause--;});}if(supportMultiTransitions(opts)===false){return false;}var requeue=false;options.requeueAttempts=options.requeueAttempts||0;$slides.each(function(){var $el=$(this);this.cycleH=(opts.fit&&opts.height)?opts.height:($el.height()||this.offsetHeight||this.height||$el.attr("height")||0);this.cycleW=(opts.fit&&opts.width)?opts.width:($el.width()||this.offsetWidth||this.width||$el.attr("width")||0);if($el.is("img")){var loadingIE=($.browser.msie&&this.cycleW==28&&this.cycleH==30&&!this.complete);var loadingFF=($.browser.mozilla&&this.cycleW==34&&this.cycleH==19&&!this.complete);var loadingOp=($.browser.opera&&((this.cycleW==42&&this.cycleH==19)||(this.cycleW==37&&this.cycleH==17))&&!this.complete);var loadingOther=(this.cycleH==0&&this.cycleW==0&&!this.complete);if(loadingIE||loadingFF||loadingOp||loadingOther){if(o.s&&opts.requeueOnImageNotLoaded&&++options.requeueAttempts<100){log(options.requeueAttempts," - img slide not loaded, requeuing slideshow: ",this.src,this.cycleW,this.cycleH);setTimeout(function(){$(o.s,o.c).cycle(options);},opts.requeueTimeout);requeue=true;return false;}else{log("could not determine size of image: "+this.src,this.cycleW,this.cycleH);}}}return true;});if(requeue){return false;}opts.cssBefore=opts.cssBefore||{};opts.animIn=opts.animIn||{};opts.animOut=opts.animOut||{};$slides.not(":eq("+first+")").css(opts.cssBefore);if(opts.cssFirst){$($slides[first]).css(opts.cssFirst);}if(opts.timeout){opts.timeout=parseInt(opts.timeout);if(opts.speed.constructor==String){opts.speed=$.fx.speeds[opts.speed]||parseInt(opts.speed);}if(!opts.sync){opts.speed=opts.speed/2;}var buffer=opts.fx=="shuffle"?500:250;while((opts.timeout-opts.speed)<buffer){opts.timeout+=opts.speed;}}if(opts.easing){opts.easeIn=opts.easeOut=opts.easing;}if(!opts.speedIn){opts.speedIn=opts.speed;}if(!opts.speedOut){opts.speedOut=opts.speed;}opts.slideCount=els.length;opts.currSlide=opts.lastSlide=first;if(opts.random){if(++opts.randomIndex==els.length){opts.randomIndex=0;}opts.nextSlide=opts.randomMap[opts.randomIndex];}else{if(opts.backwards){opts.nextSlide=opts.startingSlide==0?(els.length-1):opts.startingSlide-1;}else{opts.nextSlide=opts.startingSlide>=(els.length-1)?0:opts.startingSlide+1;}}if(!opts.multiFx){var init=$.fn.cycle.transitions[opts.fx];if($.isFunction(init)){init($cont,$slides,opts);}else{if(opts.fx!="custom"&&!opts.multiFx){log("unknown transition: "+opts.fx,"; slideshow terminating");return false;}}}var e0=$slides[first];if(opts.before.length){opts.before[0].apply(e0,[e0,e0,opts,true]);}if(opts.after.length>1){opts.after[1].apply(e0,[e0,e0,opts,true]);}if(opts.next){$(opts.next).bind(opts.prevNextEvent,function(){return advance(opts,opts.rev?-1:1);});}if(opts.prev){$(opts.prev).bind(opts.prevNextEvent,function(){return advance(opts,opts.rev?1:-1);});}if(opts.pager||opts.pagerAnchorBuilder){buildPager(els,opts);}exposeAddSlide(opts,els);return opts;}function saveOriginalOpts(opts){opts.original={before:[],after:[]};opts.original.cssBefore=$.extend({},opts.cssBefore);opts.original.cssAfter=$.extend({},opts.cssAfter);opts.original.animIn=$.extend({},opts.animIn);opts.original.animOut=$.extend({},opts.animOut);$.each(opts.before,function(){opts.original.before.push(this);});$.each(opts.after,function(){opts.original.after.push(this);});}function supportMultiTransitions(opts){var i,tx,txs=$.fn.cycle.transitions;if(opts.fx.indexOf(",")>0){opts.multiFx=true;opts.fxs=opts.fx.replace(/\s*/g,"").split(",");for(i=0;i<opts.fxs.length;i++){var fx=opts.fxs[i];tx=txs[fx];if(!tx||!txs.hasOwnProperty(fx)||!$.isFunction(tx)){log("discarding unknown transition: ",fx);opts.fxs.splice(i,1);i--;}}if(!opts.fxs.length){log("No valid transitions named; slideshow terminating.");return false;}}else{if(opts.fx=="all"){opts.multiFx=true;opts.fxs=[];for(p in txs){tx=txs[p];if(txs.hasOwnProperty(p)&&$.isFunction(tx)){opts.fxs.push(p);}}}}if(opts.multiFx&&opts.randomizeEffects){var r1=Math.floor(Math.random()*20)+30;for(i=0;i<r1;i++){var r2=Math.floor(Math.random()*opts.fxs.length);opts.fxs.push(opts.fxs.splice(r2,1)[0]);}debug("randomized fx sequence: ",opts.fxs);}return true;}function exposeAddSlide(opts,els){opts.addSlide=function(newSlide,prepend){var $s=$(newSlide),s=$s[0];if(!opts.autostopCount){opts.countdown++;}els[prepend?"unshift":"push"](s);if(opts.els){opts.els[prepend?"unshift":"push"](s);}opts.slideCount=els.length;$s.css("position","absolute");$s[prepend?"prependTo":"appendTo"](opts.$cont);if(prepend){opts.currSlide++;opts.nextSlide++;}if(!$.support.opacity&&opts.cleartype&&!opts.cleartypeNoBg){clearTypeFix($s);}if(opts.fit&&opts.width){$s.width(opts.width);}if(opts.fit&&opts.height&&opts.height!="auto"){$slides.height(opts.height);}s.cycleH=(opts.fit&&opts.height)?opts.height:$s.height();s.cycleW=(opts.fit&&opts.width)?opts.width:$s.width();$s.css(opts.cssBefore);if(opts.pager||opts.pagerAnchorBuilder){$.fn.cycle.createPagerAnchor(els.length-1,s,$(opts.pager),els,opts);}if($.isFunction(opts.onAddSlide)){opts.onAddSlide($s);}else{$s.hide();}};}$.fn.cycle.resetState=function(opts,fx){fx=fx||opts.fx;opts.before=[];opts.after=[];opts.cssBefore=$.extend({},opts.original.cssBefore);opts.cssAfter=$.extend({},opts.original.cssAfter);opts.animIn=$.extend({},opts.original.animIn);opts.animOut=$.extend({},opts.original.animOut);opts.fxFn=null;$.each(opts.original.before,function(){opts.before.push(this);});$.each(opts.original.after,function(){opts.after.push(this);});var init=$.fn.cycle.transitions[fx];if($.isFunction(init)){init(opts.$cont,$(opts.elements),opts);}};function go(els,opts,manual,fwd){if(manual&&opts.busy&&opts.manualTrump){debug("manualTrump in go(), stopping active transition");$(els).stop(true,true);opts.busy=false;}if(opts.busy){debug("transition active, ignoring new tx request");return;}var p=opts.$cont[0],curr=els[opts.currSlide],next=els[opts.nextSlide];if(p.cycleStop!=opts.stopCount||p.cycleTimeout===0&&!manual){return;}if(!manual&&!p.cyclePause&&!opts.bounce&&((opts.autostop&&(--opts.countdown<=0))||(opts.nowrap&&!opts.random&&opts.nextSlide<opts.currSlide))){if(opts.end){opts.end(opts);}return;}var changed=false;if((manual||!p.cyclePause)&&(opts.nextSlide!=opts.currSlide)){changed=true;var fx=opts.fx;curr.cycleH=curr.cycleH||$(curr).height();curr.cycleW=curr.cycleW||$(curr).width();next.cycleH=next.cycleH||$(next).height();next.cycleW=next.cycleW||$(next).width();if(opts.multiFx){if(opts.lastFx==undefined||++opts.lastFx>=opts.fxs.length){opts.lastFx=0;}fx=opts.fxs[opts.lastFx];opts.currFx=fx;}if(opts.oneTimeFx){fx=opts.oneTimeFx;opts.oneTimeFx=null;}$.fn.cycle.resetState(opts,fx);if(opts.before.length){$.each(opts.before,function(i,o){if(p.cycleStop!=opts.stopCount){return;}o.apply(next,[curr,next,opts,fwd]);});}var after=function(){$.each(opts.after,function(i,o){if(p.cycleStop!=opts.stopCount){return;}o.apply(next,[curr,next,opts,fwd]);});};debug("tx firing; currSlide: "+opts.currSlide+"; nextSlide: "+opts.nextSlide);opts.busy=1;if(opts.fxFn){opts.fxFn(curr,next,opts,after,fwd,manual&&opts.fastOnEvent);}else{if($.isFunction($.fn.cycle[opts.fx])){$.fn.cycle[opts.fx](curr,next,opts,after,fwd,manual&&opts.fastOnEvent);}else{$.fn.cycle.custom(curr,next,opts,after,fwd,manual&&opts.fastOnEvent);}}}if(changed||opts.nextSlide==opts.currSlide){opts.lastSlide=opts.currSlide;if(opts.random){opts.currSlide=opts.nextSlide;if(++opts.randomIndex==els.length){opts.randomIndex=0;}opts.nextSlide=opts.randomMap[opts.randomIndex];if(opts.nextSlide==opts.currSlide){opts.nextSlide=(opts.currSlide==opts.slideCount-1)?0:opts.currSlide+1;}}else{if(opts.backwards){var roll=(opts.nextSlide-1)<0;if(roll&&opts.bounce){opts.backwards=!opts.backwards;opts.nextSlide=1;opts.currSlide=0;}else{opts.nextSlide=roll?(els.length-1):opts.nextSlide-1;opts.currSlide=roll?0:opts.nextSlide+1;}}else{var roll=(opts.nextSlide+1)==els.length;if(roll&&opts.bounce){opts.backwards=!opts.backwards;opts.nextSlide=els.length-2;opts.currSlide=els.length-1;}else{opts.nextSlide=roll?0:opts.nextSlide+1;opts.currSlide=roll?els.length-1:opts.nextSlide-1;}}}}if(changed&&opts.pager){opts.updateActivePagerLink(opts.pager,opts.currSlide,opts.activePagerClass);}var ms=0;if(opts.timeout&&!opts.continuous){ms=getTimeout(els[opts.currSlide],els[opts.nextSlide],opts,fwd);}else{if(opts.continuous&&p.cyclePause){ms=10;}}if(ms>0){p.cycleTimeout=setTimeout(function(){go(els,opts,0,(!opts.rev&&!opts.backwards));},ms);}}$.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink=function(pager,currSlide,clsName){$(pager).each(function(){$(this).children().removeClass(clsName).eq(currSlide).addClass(clsName);});};function getTimeout(curr,next,opts,fwd){if(opts.timeoutFn){var t=opts.timeoutFn.call(curr,curr,next,opts,fwd);while((t-opts.speed)<250){t+=opts.speed;}debug("calculated timeout: "+t+"; speed: "+opts.speed);if(t!==false){return t;}}return opts.timeout;}$.fn.cycle.next=function(opts){advance(opts,opts.rev?-1:1);};$.fn.cycle.prev=function(opts){advance(opts,opts.rev?1:-1);};function advance(opts,val){var els=opts.elements;var p=opts.$cont[0],timeout=p.cycleTimeout;if(timeout){clearTimeout(timeout);p.cycleTimeout=0;}if(opts.random&&val<0){opts.randomIndex--;if(--opts.randomIndex==-2){opts.randomIndex=els.length-2;}else{if(opts.randomIndex==-1){opts.randomIndex=els.length-1;}}opts.nextSlide=opts.randomMap[opts.randomIndex];}else{if(opts.random){opts.nextSlide=opts.randomMap[opts.randomIndex];}else{opts.nextSlide=opts.currSlide+val;if(opts.nextSlide<0){if(opts.nowrap){return false;}opts.nextSlide=els.length-1;}else{if(opts.nextSlide>=els.length){if(opts.nowrap){return false;}opts.nextSlide=0;}}}}var cb=opts.onPrevNextEvent||opts.prevNextClick;if($.isFunction(cb)){cb(val>0,opts.nextSlide,els[opts.nextSlide]);}go(els,opts,1,val>=0);return false;}function buildPager(els,opts){var $p=$(opts.pager);$.each(els,function(i,o){$.fn.cycle.createPagerAnchor(i,o,$p,els,opts);});opts.updateActivePagerLink(opts.pager,opts.startingSlide,opts.activePagerClass);}$.fn.cycle.createPagerAnchor=function(i,el,$p,els,opts){var a;if($.isFunction(opts.pagerAnchorBuilder)){a=opts.pagerAnchorBuilder(i,el);debug("pagerAnchorBuilder("+i+", el) returned: "+a);}else{a='<a href="#">'+(i+1)+"</a>";}if(!a){return;}var $a=$(a);if($a.parents("body").length===0){var arr=[];if($p.length>1){$p.each(function(){var $clone=$a.clone(true);$(this).append($clone);arr.push($clone[0]);});$a=$(arr);}else{$a.appendTo($p);}}opts.pagerAnchors=opts.pagerAnchors||[];opts.pagerAnchors.push($a);$a.bind(opts.pagerEvent,function(e){e.preventDefault();opts.nextSlide=i;var p=opts.$cont[0],timeout=p.cycleTimeout;if(timeout){clearTimeout(timeout);p.cycleTimeout=0;}var cb=opts.onPagerEvent||opts.pagerClick;if($.isFunction(cb)){cb(opts.nextSlide,els[opts.nextSlide]);}go(els,opts,1,opts.currSlide<i);});if(!/^click/.test(opts.pagerEvent)&&!opts.allowPagerClickBubble){$a.bind("click.cycle",function(){return false;});}if(opts.pauseOnPagerHover){$a.hover(function(){opts.$cont[0].cyclePause++;},function(){opts.$cont[0].cyclePause--;});}};$.fn.cycle.hopsFromLast=function(opts,fwd){var hops,l=opts.lastSlide,c=opts.currSlide;if(fwd){hops=c>l?c-l:opts.slideCount-l;}else{hops=c<l?l-c:l+opts.slideCount-c;}return hops;};function clearTypeFix($slides){debug("applying clearType background-color hack");function hex(s){s=parseInt(s).toString(16);return s.length<2?"0"+s:s;}function getBg(e){for(;e&&e.nodeName.toLowerCase()!="html";e=e.parentNode){var v=$.css(e,"background-color");if(v.indexOf("rgb")>=0){var rgb=v.match(/\d+/g);return"#"+hex(rgb[0])+hex(rgb[1])+hex(rgb[2]);}if(v&&v!="transparent"){return v;}}return"#ffffff";}$slides.each(function(){$(this).css("background-color",getBg(this));});}$.fn.cycle.commonReset=function(curr,next,opts,w,h,rev){$(opts.elements).not(curr).hide();opts.cssBefore.opacity=1;opts.cssBefore.display="block";if(w!==false&&next.cycleW>0){opts.cssBefore.width=next.cycleW;}if(h!==false&&next.cycleH>0){opts.cssBefore.height=next.cycleH;}opts.cssAfter=opts.cssAfter||{};opts.cssAfter.display="none";$(curr).css("zIndex",opts.slideCount+(rev===true?1:0));$(next).css("zIndex",opts.slideCount+(rev===true?0:1));};$.fn.cycle.custom=function(curr,next,opts,cb,fwd,speedOverride){var $l=$(curr),$n=$(next);var speedIn=opts.speedIn,speedOut=opts.speedOut,easeIn=opts.easeIn,easeOut=opts.easeOut;$n.css(opts.cssBefore);if(speedOverride){if(typeof speedOverride=="number"){speedIn=speedOut=speedOverride;}else{speedIn=speedOut=1;}easeIn=easeOut=null;}var fn=function(){$n.animate(opts.animIn,speedIn,easeIn,cb);};$l.animate(opts.animOut,speedOut,easeOut,function(){if(opts.cssAfter){$l.css(opts.cssAfter);}if(!opts.sync){fn();}});if(opts.sync){fn();}};$.fn.cycle.transitions={fade:function($cont,$slides,opts){$slides.not(":eq("+opts.currSlide+")").css("opacity",0);opts.before.push(function(curr,next,opts){$.fn.cycle.commonReset(curr,next,opts);opts.cssBefore.opacity=0;});opts.animIn={opacity:1};opts.animOut={opacity:0};opts.cssBefore={top:0,left:0};}};$.fn.cycle.ver=function(){return ver;};$.fn.cycle.defaults={fx:"fade",timeout:4000,timeoutFn:null,continuous:0,speed:1000,speedIn:null,speedOut:null,next:null,prev:null,onPrevNextEvent:null,prevNextEvent:"click.cycle",pager:null,onPagerEvent:null,pagerEvent:"click.cycle",allowPagerClickBubble:false,pagerAnchorBuilder:null,before:null,after:null,end:null,easing:null,easeIn:null,easeOut:null,shuffle:null,animIn:null,animOut:null,cssBefore:null,cssAfter:null,fxFn:null,height:"auto",startingSlide:0,sync:1,random:0,fit:0,containerResize:1,pause:0,pauseOnPagerHover:0,autostop:0,autostopCount:0,delay:0,slideExpr:null,cleartype:!$.support.opacity,cleartypeNoBg:false,nowrap:0,fastOnEvent:0,randomizeEffects:1,rev:0,manualTrump:true,requeueOnImageNotLoaded:true,requeueTimeout:250,activePagerClass:"activeSlide",updateActivePagerLink:null,backwards:false};})(jQuery);
```

Not sure what to do to fix it, or even if it is what is responsible for breaking the site in IE. I would appreciate any advice in this matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but ... If you are using JQuery 1.9 or higher, add JQuery Migrate to your code and see if it will work.
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js

I am saying that because of this (part of your code)`$.browser.msie`. It's a part of JQuery that is not supported any more.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Another good link http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-1-9-breaks-cycle-lite-plugin-1-5-and-1-6

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing a minor update to the module and it seems to be functioning. For now, at least. The part of code that indicates error is

    {go(els,opts,0,(!opts.rev&&!opts.backwards))

I'm still getting the error now, even with the problem supposedly fixed. Any ideas?